# Add authentication and authorization in a Blazor Server app with Identity Server 4 using docker + kubernetes behind a NGINX reverse-proxy

Tags: nginx, identityserver4, blazor

I am trying for several days now to find out why I am unable to make NGINX as reverse proxy to work with Identity Server4 and a Blazor Server app running in docker containers.

What is happening is I am able to browse to Blazor app, press login button, I am redirected to Identity Server login page, enter user and password, accept the consent but the redirect back to the Blazor app doesn't work.

Nginx logs shows a 400 in the POST below although the Blazor App is setup to use HTTPS with a LetsEncrypt certificate.

```
[06/Dec/2019:15:45:34 +0000] "GET /account/login HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://dev.codescu.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
[06/Dec/2019:15:45:34 +0000] "GET /connect/authorize?client_id=sdehelperwebui&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.codescu.com%2Fsignin-oidc&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=637112439340098608.NGY4ZGY2MWQtNTQyNy00NWRlLThiNjUtOWFjYjJhMDE0MzhiMTFkYTc3NmUtMGRlMi00Y2MwLWI0MWYtNTY2MzUzOWFlOGVk&state=CfDJ8KMZi0b-1bJCq1rFhJ3cRbHrbVT7oo9NFGXrRCXzkFjao9vVEBAMSvpBPimLtESIVXxpNOgMCQddEfRBwniwkNoDZzdVdQdViLWoSDdfm_Eftppnhnz77okwELuUANmR7DNixxpiSbDvSB8WhW-zrwrXjPjgDaja7tRST1Vvd_K-cDBiEu8ZsYXpkkNEhoMqhYHnBiD6JhYUIgto99pbUyjVtAFxDKvHBWEfwDVstQsLjh2ld4hPagk3jLYN0G0Od9aMQrkU5tqRf_B4_gZoYJgrjs8jkI7c3d2oksH0wACc&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=5.5.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "https://dev.codescu.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
[06/Dec/2019:15:45:34 +0000] "GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dsdehelperwebui%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdev.codescu.com%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D637112439340098608.NGY4ZGY2MWQtNTQyNy00NWRlLThiNjUtOWFjYjJhMDE0MzhiMTFkYTc3NmUtMGRlMi00Y2MwLWI0MWYtNTY2MzUzOWFlOGVk%26state%3DCfDJ8KMZi0b-1bJCq1rFhJ3cRbHrbVT7oo9NFGXrRCXzkFjao9vVEBAMSvpBPimLtESIVXxpNOgMCQddEfRBwniwkNoDZzdVdQdViLWoSDdfm_Eftppnhnz77okwELuUANmR7DNixxpiSbDvSB8WhW-zrwrXjPjgDaja7tRST1Vvd_K-cDBiEu8ZsYXpkkNEhoMqhYHnBiD6JhYUIgto99pbUyjVtAFxDKvHBWEfwDVstQsLjh2ld4hPagk3jLYN0G0Od9aMQrkU5tqRf_B4_gZoYJgrjs8jkI7c3d2oksH0wACc%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NETSTANDARD2_0%26x-client-ver%3D5.5.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 2177 "https://dev.codescu.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
[06/Dec/2019:15:45:34 +0000] "GET /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dsdehelperwebui%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdev.codescu.com%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D637112439340098608.NGY4ZGY2MWQtNTQyNy00NWRlLThiNjUtOWFjYjJhMDE0MzhiMTFkYTc3NmUtMGRlMi00Y2MwLWI0MWYtNTY2MzUzOWFlOGVk%26state%3DCfDJ8KMZi0b-1bJCq1rFhJ3cRbHrbVT7oo9NFGXrRCXzkFjao9vVEBAMSvpBPimLtESIVXxpNOgMCQddEfRBwniwkNoDZzdVdQdViLWoSDdfm_Eftppnhnz77okwELuUANmR7DNixxpiSbDvSB8WhW-zrwrXjPjgDaja7tRST1Vvd_K-cDBiEu8ZsYXpkkNEhoMqhYHnBiD6JhYUIgto99pbUyjVtAFxDKvHBWEfwDVstQsLjh2ld4hPagk3jLYN0G0Od9aMQrkU5tqRf_B4_gZoYJgrjs8jkI7c3d2oksH0wACc%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NETSTANDARD2_0%26x-client-ver%3D5.5.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 200 2176 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
[06/Dec/2019:15:45:35 +0000] "POST /Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dsdehelperwebui%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fdev.codescu.com%252Fsignin-oidc%26response_type%3Dcode%2520id_token%26scope%3Dopenid%2520profile%26response_mode%3Dform_post%26nonce%3D637112439340098608.NGY4ZGY2MWQtNTQyNy00NWRlLThiNjUtOWFjYjJhMDE0MzhiMTFkYTc3NmUtMGRlMi00Y2MwLWI0MWYtNTY2MzUzOWFlOGVk%26state%3DCfDJ8KMZi0b-1bJCq1rFhJ3cRbHrbVT7oo9NFGXrRCXzkFjao9vVEBAMSvpBPimLtESIVXxpNOgMCQddEfRBwniwkNoDZzdVdQdViLWoSDdfm_Eftppnhnz77okwELuUANmR7DNixxpiSbDvSB8WhW-zrwrXjPjgDaja7tRST1Vvd_K-cDBiEu8ZsYXpkkNEhoMqhYHnBiD6JhYUIgto99pbUyjVtAFxDKvHBWEfwDVstQsLjh2ld4hPagk3jLYN0G0Od9aMQrkU5tqRf_B4_gZoYJgrjs8jkI7c3d2oksH0wACc%26x-client-SKU%3DID_NETSTANDARD2_0%26x-client-ver%3D5.5.0.0 HTTP/1.1" 400 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
```

Nginx configuration:

```
server {

        server_name dev.codescu.com;

        location / {


#            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://api.localhost';
#            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
#            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
#            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://api.localhost';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
      add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
      add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
      add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
      return 204;
}


                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass https://10.190.26.242;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
                fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
        }

        real_ip_header proxy_protocol;
        set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;

    listen [::]:443 ssl proxy_protocol ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl proxy_protocol; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/codescu.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/codescu.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = dev.codescu.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 proxy_protocol;

        server_name dev.codescu.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
```

The same setup was made for the Identity Server4 virtual host.

In the code I have added:

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
```

in both Blazor and Identity Server projects.

I've tried to run both Blazor & Identity Server apps with or without TLS.

It is worth mentioning that browsing locally, without the need to have the traffic routed via reverse proxy, works.

When I try to browse from "outside" and I need to use the Nginx reverse-proxy, when I am redirected back to the Blazor app it stops workings.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have kestrel logs and response browser logs ? Maybe those logs can tell what's wrong.

Comment: Kestrel doesn't show anything because the traffic is not even reaching the Blazor app after is being redirected from IdentityServer.

Browser shows a 400, just like in Nginx logs.

Comment: If you just send a POST request, is it blocked ?

Comment: try this : remove this line from the config proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade'; changed it into proxy_set_header Connection ''; https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/867

Comment: That worked, please add a proper answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the issue [867](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/867), the **Nginx proxy_set_header Connection** should be empty

Update your Nginx configuration with:

```
proxy_set_header Connection '';
```